# Does "-che" in "douche" and "gauche" have meaning?

Tags: suffixes

"douche" means shower, and "gauche" means awkward, and lacking social experience or grace.

Does "-che" in "douche" and "gauche" have meaning?

Comment: Sure, the same meaning they have in *pastiche*, *gouache*, *affiche* and other words. That is, they are French word endings and the endings carry no more special meanings in English than the *-che* endings do in *bellyache* and *Apache*. If you like, you may overlay [any meanings you want](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Che_guevara), but that's not likely to do anyone any good.

Comment: It's a mark (especially when spelled CHE) that the word is borrowed from French, which means it's gone through Romance palatalization, which changed Latin final stops to Romance final sibilants, producing the final /ʃ/ sound in /duʃ/ from an original Latin root _duc-_ 'lead', borrowed into English in hundreds of words like _ductile, duke, reduction, induce, produce_. The spellings with C in French, Spanish, and Italian are relics of the original Latin C, which represented the Latin phoneme /k/. Always.

Comment: @John Lawler  Interesting. And doesn't the fact that Latin has a neuter gender, whilst French has none, play a part here. *che is a classic feminine ending. With some adjectives, it is the method of switching from masculine to feminine e.g. blanc; blanche

Comment: Nah, not particularly. French never had a neuter; the Latin neuter merged with the masculine in Vulgar Latin [via grammaticalization](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TheGrammaticalizationCycle.pdf) long before Franks were speaking any Romance language. After that, noun genders can get reassigned for other purpose; in Quebecois French, for instance, it's common to swap genders for any noun that's normally one or the other to call attention to some (contextually determined) unusual feature of the thing being referred to.

Answer (score 2):

There's no meaning. It is not a separable suffix that can be used at the end of other words.

Both those words happen to be direct loans from French (not that that makes the endings non-separable, see 'Mar-athon'). The spelling and sound 'che' come from a transformation/sound change from the original Latin ending '-ca' which is also not productive in Latin (or the transformed version in French). It's just a word ending in '-ca'.